# C# Microsoft.Office.Interop

Tags: c#, ms-office, office-interop

I need to reference this library, however when I right click and go to add references, I can't find it in the list.

I have office 2007 installed.

```
C# Microsoft.Office.Interop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to Install Office Primary Interop Assemblies first. You can download it from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18346